# How to count items in a table based on the main query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay guys say I am currently doing this query:

```
SELECT `category_id`, `category_name` 
FROM `database_categorys` 
ORDER BY `category_name` ASC
```

Now I want to count all rows from a table called "database_items" where the item table's category id is equal to the current rows category id.

Some sort of join or nested query I am guessing but I cannot wrap my head around the correct syntax to do it.

So that when echoing it out I can do:

```
<category name> <total items in category number>
```

Comment: How are you linking the tables?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT c.`category_id`, c.`category_name`, count(i.`category_id`)
FROM `database_categorys` c
LEFT OUTER JOIN `database_items` i on c.`category_id` = i.`category_id`
GROUP BY c.`category_id`, c.`category_name`
ORDER BY c.`category_name`
```

Comment: Thanks but i needed category_id as well but that's basically what i was after thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use subqueries like this:

```
SELECT 
    `category_id`, `category_name`,
    (SELECT count(1) from database_items i where i.category_id = c.category_id)
FROM `database_categorys` c 
ORDER BY `category_name` ASC
```

Comment: why `count(1)`? Do you mean `count(*)`

Comment: You can use count(id), but once a DBA told me that count(1) would be little bit faster than count(id). Basically, both of them counting records ...

Comment: It's moot in this case because using a correlated scalar subquery in the select-list is far worse for performance than the slight difference between count(1) and count(*).